# Percentage Precision in bash

Tags: bash, precision

Here's the culprit line of code in my bash script:

```
bat_percent=`echo "$bat_percent * 100" | bc | sed 's/.00//'`
```

When the bat_percent would otherwise put out 100, it puts out .00

If I were to change it to: (removing a . and adding a 0)

```
bat_percent=`echo "$bat_percent * 100" | bc | sed 's/000//'`
```

Or even: (3 0's and a .)

```
bat_percent=`echo "$bat_percent * 100" | bc | sed 's/000.//'`
```

The output is 100.00

How in the heck do I just get it to say 100, while maintaining other percentages as, say, 87 or 5?

I'll be around to answer any follow-ups :)

***POST-MORTEM***

Here's the finished code, thanks to the help from y'all! (Also: stop down voting each other! Let's just be friends, m'kay?)

```
my_ac_adapt=`ioreg -w0 -l | grep ExternalConnected | awk '{print $5}'` 
cur_power=`ioreg -w0 -l | grep CurrentCapacity | awk '{print $5}'` 
max_power=`ioreg -w0 -l | grep MaxCapacity | awk '{print $5}'` 
bat_percent=`echo "scale=2;$cur_power / $max_power" | bc` 
bat_percent=`echo "$bat_percent * 100" | bc | sed 's/\..*//'` 
if [ "$my_ac_adapt" == "Yes" -a "$bat_percent" == "100" ] 
then 
echo "Charged" 
elif [ "$my_ac_adapt" == "Yes" -a "$bat_percent" != "100" ] 
then 
echo "Charging: $bat_percent%" 
else 
echo "Battery: $bat_percent%" 
fi
```

This code gets the current state of your battery and informs you thusly :)

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your question. What is the initial value of `$bat_percent`?

Comment: $bat_percent is a system call that gets the % of battery life left in a laptop battery. It constantly changes. That initial value won't have anything to do with my question, though, as I'm only trying to format output.

Comment: Right. I *think* that was you want is to have '100' when `$bat_percent` is already `100`? Or something? You should really provide some example values for `$bat_percent`. Also, why did you revert my edit? I thought it was constructive and make things a but clearer? In all honesty, I had to read your question 4 times and I'm *still* not 100% sure what you're asking...

Comment: I did provide some, actually. All I'm asking is pretty simple: the last bit of that code is NORMALLY okay with a number like 99    But as soon as it becomes 100, it is displayed as .00, which I presume is from the last bit of code there. So, as explained in the question, I tried changing it to 000, and then I get 100.00...which is BETTER, but I don't want the .00 at the end. When it's 100, it should say 100. When it's 99, it should say 99. When it's 1, it should say 1. When it's 0, it should theoretically say 0, but the computer will be dead ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `sed 's/.00//'` it basically means match any character (meaning of `.`) followed by `00` and replace it with nothing. So when you have `100.00` in your output, `sed` duly removes `100` from it and gives you `.00`.

What you really need is to escape the special character with `\`

`... | sed 's/\..*//'`

Comment: This is precisely what I need, and your explanation was spot on. Thank you for being accurate, concise, and very much to the point. I really appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
bat_percent=`echo "$bat_percent * 100" | bc | sed 's/\.00//'`
```

The problem with your `sed` command is that you haven't escaped the `.` as `\.` to use it as a literal; an unescaped `.` in a regular expression matches ANY character.

If the input is `"100.00"`, `/.00/` matches `100` (because `.`, due to matching any char., matches the `1`), not `.00`.

Alternatively, if you always just want to drop the fractional part, try this:

```
bat_percent=$(bc <<<"$bat_percent * 100" | cut -d'.' -f 1)
```

Comment: I tried your solution as well as the answer that I chose, and yours indeed worked as well! Just for continuity with a few other lines of code that DON'T ever return decimals, I decided to accept the other answer. Thank you very much, though. I learned a lot from your explanation, it was very helpful!

Comment: @Joodoo: My pleasure. If - and only if - you think that others may find useful information in my answer _in addition_ to the answer you accepted, you can still up-vote it.

Comment: I did, some other jackwagon down voted you right before I up-voted it. Otherwise you'd be negative. I'm sorry about that :(

Comment: Here's some proof, just because it really ticked me off that someone voted down a perfectly good answer: http://imgur.com/9DOWFEX

Comment: @Joodoo Thanks for up-voting and for taking the time to let me know what happened - much appreciated. To the down-voter: it would be helpful to explain why, so the answer can be improved, if need be.

Comment: @mklement0 You have my +1 too. :)

Comment: @Joodoo: Btw, before you let me know, I had noticed that your question was downvoted, so I neutralized that. Just stumbled across a feature in this context: if you click on the vote tally (the number) next to a question, it expands to show the breakdown into up/downvotes.

Comment: @Joodoo I believe someone is trying to secure downvoting badge! ;)

Comment: @mklement0 It's a conspiracy! Also, if ya like, I posted the entire script above in the original question now that it's complete and finally freaking working as intended.

Comment: @jaypalsingh What a f***** t*** a***** d***** and all that other stuff. When I down vote, it's because I care, not because I want a badge! ;)

Comment: @Joodoo: Thanks for posting the code; in case performance matters: you could speed things up by (a) invoking ioreg only once and (b) limiting its output to the properties of interest; here's a fast command that replaces the first 3 lines of your code: `read my_ac_adapt max_power cur_power < <(ioreg -rd1 -c AppleSmartBattery | egrep -o '"(ExternalConnected|CurrentCapacity|MaxCapacity)" = (.+)' | awk -F ' = ' '{printf "%s ", $2}')` - note, however, that this relies on `ioreg`'s output ordering of values.

Comment: @mklement0 Awesome, thanks a bunch! I'll definitely look into that tonight!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
$ bat_percent=.999

$ awk "BEGIN{printf \"%d\",$bat_percent*100}"
99
```

```
$ bat_percent=1.000

$ awk "BEGIN{printf \"%d\",$bat_percent*100}"
100
```